# Resizing Uploading Images in Bulk?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, images

I have been running a blog for a friend and over the last months she has been adding insane amounts of images taken directly from a DSLR.  Each takes up around  5-6 MB so the site is now  slow to load and is consuming large amounts of bandwidth and disk size.

I was looking on the [smush.it](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-smushit/) plugin, but it doesn't seem to do it ad-hock and also, doesn't do bulk resize. Is there some easy way to fix this on the server with a plugin? Would prefer that instead of download all images and do bulk resize. Big thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the bulk image resize utility:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bulk-image-resize-utility/

I have used that numerous times and it does a fantastic job!

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. Is it also possible to run it when she uploads images automatically?

Comment: *@grm* - Why not rename this question *"Resizing Uploading Images in Bulk?"* and then ask a new question entitled *"Resizing Imaging Upon Upload?"* as the solutions for each will differ.

Comment: WordPress already automatically resizes your images into all registered image sizes on upload. You can add as many image sizes as you like with `add_image_size( <name (string)>, <width (int)>, <height (int)>, <crop (bool)> )`.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) would be a great tool for automatically resizing the images on upload. Hacking your theme's functions.php file ([described here](http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-imagemagick-with-wordpress-2-9-1/)) is one way to get this up and running. Of course, you'll need ImageMagick installed on your web host.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload images outside like on flickr, then you can use their API while accessing the image.