# Can images be automatically compressed?

Tags: images

having trouble educating clients to compress their images, and would quite like wordpress to compress images to predefined size (normally, 800px long edge, 72dpi) and discard the original

Comment: Some related discussion on this question [Decrease image size](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/decrease-image-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-image-resizer/ 
 Add this to your functions.php:

```
function prune_image_sizes($sizes) {
// You can add other size like that for remove those sizes
//  unset($sizes['medium']);
    unset($sizes['large']);

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'prune_image_sizes');
```

Set your large image option to 800px in media options panel.

So what did you do? System will not create large size of image but will reduce original image size to large size ( 800px ) option. Most of developer dont like it but when client have to upload lots of image and dont have hosting space so much, this will helps.
(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3):

Tried this plugin?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-image-resizer/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the `$content_width` global variable (in your theme's `functions.php` for example), all images will be resized to be no wider than that. Remember to also change the settings for the large image size, otherwise [it will be confusing to users why they can't use that size anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089844/content-width-wordpress).

Comment: I think that unless you override it somewhere, WordPress will try to define the "large" image size to the value you set in $content_width (and then correspondingly set the "medium" and "small" sizes proportionally)...

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about discarding the original images to conserve space. I think you might have to hook the 'add_attachment' action to delete the original after resizing. In combination with Jan's suggestion about setting your $content_width variable to your maximum size, this should do the trick.